# Jquery Validation still allowing POST back despite conditions not being met

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Weird, real weird.

I have some Jquery Validation statements that still allow a post back despite the conditions of that Validation not being met.  Here are my statements...

```
$("#temp1").validate({
        rules: {
            HospitalFinNumber: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6
            },
            DateOfBirth: {
                required: true
            },
            AdmitDate: {
                required: true
            },
            Comment: {
                required: function (element) {
                    return $(element).val().length < 4000;
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            HospitalFinNumber: 'Please Enter a Hospital Fin number',
            DateOfBirth: 'Please enter a valid Date Of Birth',
            AdmitDate: 'Please select an Admit Date',
            Comment: 'Why dont you stop attempting to put in more than 4000 characters?  Thanks...'
    });
});
```

I could have sworn that they were working before

Comment: have you got some errors in javascript console after validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer to my question...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9197441/729820

Answer (score 2):

You have javascript errors in the script you have shown. Why aren't you looking at your console? Why aren't you using javascript debugging tools such as FireBug or some developer toolbar? How can you possibly be doing any web development without a debugging tool? Had you used a debugging tool it would have indicated you the exact error and its location. So fix your javascript:

```
$("#temp1").validate({
        rules: {
            HospitalFinNumber: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6
            },
            DateOfBirth: {
                required: true
            },
            AdmitDate: {
                required: true
            },
            Comment: {
                required: function (element) {
                    return $(element).val().length < 4000;
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            HospitalFinNumber: 'Please Enter a Hospital Fin number',
            DateOfBirth: 'Please enter a valid Date Of Birth',
            AdmitDate: 'Please select an Admit Date',
            Comment: 'Why dont you stop attempting to put in more than 4000 characters?  Thanks...'
        }
});
```

Notice the closing `});` at the end. In your code snippet you have them twice.

Comment: As a point of interest, should we down-vote this question? Thanks for checking the code Darin, didn't event think to check! :)

Comment: I got to tell ya, I have been having a hell of a time getting that console to open.  I am using IE 8 (what the users will be using) and visual studio to debug... and for some reason, the developer tools won't open.  Oh sorry...  that is just the closing bracket for a $(document).ready(function(){

Comment: @ChrisKempen, dunno what we should do with such questions. There are hundreds of questions where the OP simply doesn't debug their code.

Comment: @DmainEvent, how on the holy mother of Earth you can use IE8 to do web development?????? How do you expect to do some serious stuff with *this* (don't know how to call it). Use a real web browser to do development. If you have a requirement for your site to work under IE8 you could test it but never, I repeat, NEVER use this thing for web development. I mean, you are simply wasting your time.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov It aint easy.  But I would rather do it from jump street than to develop with Chrome and then have to switch back and run into some issue with the conversion.  I don't think it will have that much of an impact.  But what browser would you recommend?  I like Chrome, But is there another more developer friendly browser to work with?

Comment: @DmainEvent, you can test features as you implement them in IE8. But don't, I repeat, don't implement anything in IE8. This *thing* is not for implementing. It's not even for surfing but, well, some people use it for that, so we have to suffer. You might consider IE9 (even if I wouldn't) for web development as it has some developer toolbar that might even tell you that you have javascript errors.

Comment: Ok weird.  I just published the site to a test server, and attempted to submit without the correct Validation conditions set and it worked... On Chrome no less.  Now I have to figure out why IE 8 isn't doing it.  :(