# jquery Validate not validating input in IE 8

Tags: jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation and it is not catching instances where the validation conditions are not met?  This is curious to me, partly, because it was working before (I am using IE 8 in compatibility mode now, would that affect something?)...
There don't seem to be any compilation exceptions off the top of my head?  Does where I import the jquery validation src file affect how it works???  Here is my code...

```
$("#temp1").validate({
        rules: {
            HospitalFinNumber: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6
            },
            DateOfBirth: {
                required: true
            },
            AdmitDate: {
                required: true
            },
            Comment: {
                required: function (element) {
                    return $(element).val().length < 4000;
                },
                maxlength: 4000
            }
        },
        messages: {
            HospitalFinNumber: 'Please Enter a Hospital Fin number',
            DateOfBirth: 'Please enter a valid Date Of Birth',
            AdmitDate: 'Please select an Admit Date',
            Comment: 'Why dont you stop attempting to put in more than 4000 characters?  Thanks...'
        }
    });
```

Here are my includes into source...

```
<script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.timeentry.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/charCount.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.filter_input.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/simpleTimeMask.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

form elements:

```
<div class="edit-set" id="EditTemplate">
<form action="/PatientACO/UpdateXML?template=592&amp;PopPatId=1139&amp;EncOrAdd=0" id="temp1" method="post" name="editTemp"><div class="validation-summary-valid" id="validationSummary"><ul><li style="display:none"></li>
</ul></div>
  Activate/Deactivate Patient 
  <div id="deactivateNO" style="display:none"><input id="deactivate" name="deactivate" type="radio" value="N" />Deactivate</div>
  <div id="deactivateYES" style="display:none"><input id="deactivate" name="deactivate" type="radio" value="A" />Activate</div>
  <table width="500" class="odd"><tr><td><label for="BLUE">First Name</label></td><td>     <input id="element6" name="FirstName" readonly="True" type="text" value="BLUE" /></td></tr>  <tr><td><label for="CRAYON">Last Name</label></td><td><input id="element7" name="LastName" readonly="True" type="text" value="CRAYON" /></td></tr><tr><td><label for="10/31/1966 12:00:00 AM">Date Of Birth</label></td><td><input class="datepicker0" id="date0" name="DateOfBirth" type="text" value="10/31/1966" /><!--supposed to be date input --></td></tr><tr><td><label for="4111111111">Phone</label></td><td><input id="Phone" name="Phone" type="text" value="4111111111" /><!--string input -->                        
                    </td></tr><tr><td><label for="111 222 333 444">Hospital Fin Number (**required**)</label></td><td><input id="HospitalFinNumber" name="HospitalFinNumber" type="text" value="" /><!--string input -->                        
                    </td></tr><tr><td><label for="29-DEC-11">Admit Date (**required**)</label></td><td><input class="datepicker1" id="AdmitDate" name="AdmitDate" type="text" value="" /><!--supposed to be date input -->&nbsp</td></tr><tr><td><label for="MPACMRN">MRN Type</label></td><td><select id="MPACMRN" name="MRNType"><option selected="selected" value="MPACMRN">Medipac</option>
<option value="NWMRN">NorthWest</option>
<option value="EPIC">Epic</option>
<option value="BEDFORD">Bedford</option>
<option value="CHILDRENS">Childrens</option>
<option value="MAGEE">Magee</option>
<option value="PASSAVANT">Passavant</option>
<option value="MERCY">Mercy</option>
<option value="BEST">Medicare</option>
<option value="HEALTHPLAN">UPMC Health Plan</option>
<option value="EMPIID">EMPI</option>
</select></td></tr><tr><td><label for="840015579">MRN</label></td><td><input id="MRN" name="MRN" type="text" value="840015579" /></td></tr><tr><td><label for="">Patient Room Phone</label></td><td><input id="PatientRoomPhone" name="PatientRoomPhone" type="text" value="" /><!--string input -->                        
                    </td></tr><tr><td><label for="">Discharge Date Time</label></td><td><input class="datepicker2" id="DischargeDateTime" name="DischargeDateTime" type="text" value="" /><!--supposed to be date input -->&nbsp<input id="DischargeDateTimeMask" name="DischargeDateTimeMask" type="text" value="" /><!--supposed to be date input --></td></tr><tr><td><label for="">Discharge Disposition</label></td><td><input id="DischargeDisposition" name="DischargeDisposition" type="text" value="" /><!--string input -->                        
                    </td></tr><tr><td><label for="">Discharge To</label></td><td><input id="DischargeTo" name="DischargeTo" type="text" value="" /><!--string input -->                        
                    </td></tr><tr><td><label for="1">Discharge Advocate Call</label> </td><td><input checked="checked" id="element18" name="DischargeAdvocateCall" type="radio" value="1" />Yes<input id="element18" name="DischargeAdvocateCall" type="radio" value="0" />No</td></tr><tr><td><label for="">Payor</label></td><td><input id="Payor" name="Payor" type="text" value="" /><!--string input -->                        
                    </td></tr><tr><td><label for="1">Home Healthcare Accepted</label> </td><td><input checked="checked" id="element20" name="HomeHealthCareAccepted" type="radio" value="1" />Yes<input id="element20" name="HomeHealthCareAccepted" type="radio" value="0" />No</td></tr><tr><td><label for="1">Safe Landing Accepted</label></td><td><input checked="checked" id="element21" name="SafeLandingAccepted" type="radio" value="1" />Yes<input id="element21" name="SafeLandingAccepted" type="radio" value="0" />No</td></tr> <tr><td><label for="">PCP Name</label></td><td><input id="PCPName" name="PCPName" type="text" value="" /><!--string input -->                        
                    </td></tr><tr><td><label for="">PCP Phone</label></td><td><input id="PCPPhone" name="PCPPhone" type="text" value="" /><!--string input -->                        
                    </td></tr><tr><td><label for="">Specialist Name</label></td><td> <input id="SpecialistName" name="SpecialistName" type="text" value="" /><!--string input -->                        
                    </td></tr><tr><td><label for="">Specialist Phone</label></td><td> <input id="SpecialistPhone" name="SpecialistPhone" type="text" value="" /><!--string input -->                        
                    </td></tr><tr><td><label for="">PCP Appointment Date Time</label> </td><td><input class="datepicker3" id="PCPAppointmentDateTime" name="PCPAppointmentDateTime" type="text" value="" /><!--supposed to be date input -->&nbsp<input id="PCPAppointmentDateTimeMask" name="PCPAppointmentDateTimeMask" type="text" value="" /><!--supposed to be date input --></td></tr><tr><td><label for="">PCP Appointment Location</label></td><td><input id="PCPAppointmentLocation" name="PCPAppointmentLocation" type="text" value="" /><!--string input -->                        
                    </td></tr><tr><td><label for="">Specialist Appointment Date Time</label></td><td><input class="datepicker4" id="SpecialistAppointmentDateTime" name="SpecialistAppointmentDateTime" type="text" value="" /><!--supposed to be date input -->&nbsp<input id="SpecialistAppointmentDateTimeMask" name="SpecialistAppointmentDateTimeMask" type="text" value="" /><!--supposed to be date input --></td></tr><tr><td><label for="">Specialist Appointment Location</label></td><td><input id="SpecialistAppointmentLocation" name="SpecialistAppointmentLocation" type="text" value="" /><!--string input -->                        
                    </td></tr><tr><td><label for="">Completed Pathway</label></td><td><input id="element30" name="CompletedPathway" type="radio" value="1" />Yes<input id="element30" name="CompletedPathway" type="radio" value="0" />No</td></tr><tr><td><label for="">Completed Pathway Reason</label></td><td><input id="CompletedPathwayReason" name="CompletedPathwayReason" type="text" value="" /><!--string input -->                        
                    </td></tr><tr><td><label for="Testing the Add function on my development setup.">Comment</label></td><td><textarea cols="60" id="element32" name="Comment" rows="10">
</textarea></td></tr></table> 
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="button" id="btClick"/>
</p> 
</div>
</form>
```

Also, I just noticed that it is not working in ie 8 but it is working in chrome?  Could there be some browser compatibility problems?

Comment: What about the HTML elements you are trying to validate?

Comment: If that really is all of your includes, you're missing jQuery itself.

Comment: I have my jquery on my main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery Validate version 1.9 seems to have fixed the problem... 
[Link to version 1.9](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

I had to add it to my project as a package.  Which I find is weird.  But what the heck ever.